# Powershell script to setin a word infront of every word?

Tags: powershell

So is it possible to make a powershell script that takes a line of word i pick, and set it infront of every word.

I got a .txt file with over 24mil words in it, and i need the word "guid:" infront of every word.

Is there a way to make a script that dose this?

Comment: If you need it done, hire somebody. If you need help *doing it yourself*, give it a try and then come ask a *specific* question to a *specific* problem you encounter.

Comment: "Is there a way to make a script that dose this?". Yes, there is.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $content = Get-Content 'C:\Temp2\testStack.txt'


  foreach($item in $content)
  {
     if($item.Contains("TEST"))
     {
         $item = "PREFIX" + $item
     }

    Out-File -FilePath C:\Temp2\testStack2.txt -Append -InputObject $item
  }
```

Here is an easy way although there are a lot of variables in play. Here I have a text file located in folder named temp2 called teststack.txt. In this file line contains "TEST" it ADDS "PREFIX" as a prefix to it and writes back all items to a new file named testSTACK2.txt. I recommend you get the book "Learn Powershell in a Month of Lunches." This book is very handy.

Comment: Hi. Thx for the answer. But every line dosent contain the same word, its a list with over 24mil GUIDs, no GUID isent the same. So is there a way to get "GUID:" infront of every GUID, none of the GUID is the same

Comment: Ok no worries. Is each one on a new line? If so that is easy to get around. If multiple on same line is there a separator? Such as a comma, pipe, etc? Better yet respond with a demo of the first few lines of the file. Thanks.